# NGINX and PHP, TLS version

Tags: php, nginx, ssl

Is it possible than NGINX can pass to PHP (PHP-FPM) some parameter which indicates with what version of TLS protocol client (browser) was connected?

Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER);` it's probably in there

Comment: No, it isn't...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.howsmyssl.com Has a free API that developers can use to get the clients TLS version.

You can have the client do this:

JS:

```
<script>
   function parseTLS(TLSinf) {
      console.log(TLSinf)
    }
</script>

<script src="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo">
```

This will instruct howsmyssl to return a Javascript where the ssl data is packaged as a function parameter for the callback function.
when the script loads it will call the callback function and the callback function will log the clients ssl status. instead of logging the ssl status you can send it to the server inform of a get or post request.

Comment: Ok, I mean my own web server that can accept TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 connection

Comment: And I want to show some message to user that connected to MY SERVER (not someelse server) with TLS1.0 or TLS1.1

Comment: Users can connect without browser using custom Json protocol. It this case this doesnt' help

Comment: In that case you need to write an NGINX module that passes the information to PHP